# Difference between ramp - up period and uniform random timer in jmeter

Tags: timer, jmeter

What is the difference between ramp - up period and uniform random timer in jmeter

and when to use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(from the JMeter manual)

Ramp-up period:

> How long JMeter should take to get all the threads started. If there
>   are 10 threads and a ramp-up time of 100 seconds, then each thread
>   will begin 10 seconds after the previous thread started, for a total
>   time of 100 seconds to get the test fully up to speed.

Uniform Random Timer:

> This timer pauses each thread request for a random amount of time,
>   with each time interval having the same probability of occurring. The
>   total delay is the sum of the random value and the offset value.

I would use Ramp-up period only at the beginning of my test, where I want a number of threads/users to begin the test over a fixed period (e.g I want every user logged in and running their tests after 1 minute)

Uniform Random Timer I would use in the middle of my tests, where I want to introduce random gaps to the tests. You could use Uniform Random Timer to do something *similar* to the Ramp-up period, but, because it's random, you don't have the same guarantee that all tests will be started after the period, that you do with Ramp-up Period.